# Check if list type of type alias

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Imagine you have a function, type hinted with an Enum subclass:

```
def x(p: CreditScore):
  pass
```

Then you can do:

```
import inspect
from enum import Enum

sig = inspect.signature(x)
annot = sig.parameters.get('p').annotation
>>> issubclass(annot, Enum)
True
```

But how would you check for the same, if it is a list of enums?

```
def x(p: List[CreditScore]):
  pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by means of [typing.get_args()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args), which for a typing object of the form `X[Y, Z, ...]` returns a tuple `(Y, Z, ...)`.

```
sig = inspect.signature(x)
annot = sig.parameters.get('p').annotation
annot_args = typing.get_args(annot)
print(issubclass(annot_args[0], Enum))
```